# How to make div's width stretch with content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a dynamic dialog control that can be used for any type of content required for that dialog. It contains a primary container, header (for dialog title), body content and footer (for buttons). I've managed to get it working so the height is dynamically adjusting based on the content and view height of the window, but I can't get the width to do the same.

Here's what I've got so far. As you can see the width of the dialog is being forced to use the max-width that is defined as apposed to using that CSS definition only when the content requires it.

```css
.dialog-box2{
  position: relative;
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: calc(90vw - 100px); 
  margin: 20px auto;
  margin-bottom: 0; 
}

.dialog-content{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba (0,0,0,.2);
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow:0 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  margin-top: 100px;
  min-height: 185px;
}

.dialog-header{
  min-height: 6.43px
  padding: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.dialog-title{
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin:0;
  line-height: 1.43;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0290d7;
 }

h3{
  font-size: 16px;
 }

.dialog-body{
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  max-height: calc(85vh - 250px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.dialog-footer{
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
 }

/*---------- for testing only ---------------------*/
.profile-btn{
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #0290D7;
  width: 120px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
  padding-top: 35px;
  color: #0290D7;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="dialog-box2">
          <div class="dialog-content">
            <div class="dialog-header">
              <h3 class="dialog-title" id="myDialogLabelDefault">Dialog Title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="dialog-body">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum nisi est sed incidunt magni maxime? Praesentium itaque sed nihil veritatis. Dolorem autem, alias reprehenderit facilis deserunt voluptatum dolore natus. Impedit.</p>
              
                <div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div><!-- 
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>
                  <div class="profile-btn">Thing</div>-->
                </div>
              
            </div>
            <div class="dialog-footer">
              <div class="prev">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-outline">Save as Profile</button>
              </div>
              <div class="sc-next">
                <button type="button" class="btn-link dialog-cancel" data-close="dialog">Cancel</button>
                <span class="sc-dialog-bullet"></span>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-outline">Outlined 2nd Btn</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Here is an example of what I'm getting with the above code and where the issue lies, in case my explanation of what I'm trying to accomplish isn't clear. 
[image]

What am I doing wrong, I feel like I've tried everything I can think of.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try using a percentage % for your width instead of a fixed number, and encapsulate it within a wrapper div if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `display: flex;` or `display:inline-block;`

```
.dialog-box2{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 min-width: 400px;
 max-width: 90%; 
 margin: 20px auto;
 margin-bottom: 0; 
}
```

You'll probably have to properly center the div, but the content should adapt just fine.

Comment: Sadly, I've tried both options previously and neither had the desired affect.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `max-width` property from the `.dialog-box2` div.

Comment: sadly, all that does is allow the dialog's width to stretch 100% instead of conforming and only stretching to the width needed based on the content.

Answer (score 0):

Setting any of the width columns prevents the div from stretching but unsetting all the widths allows the element to stretch...

```
.dialog-box2{
    min-width: unset;
    width: unset;
    max-width: unset;
}
```

The flex attribute is needed for the page layout with respect to other elements on the page but doesn't play into the solution to the question, so I've omitted it.